Relationship between covers of base of blow-up and blow-up?
Suppose we have the following set-up
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y @<{\exists ?}<< \widetilde{\mathrm{Bl}_Z X};\\
@V{f}VV @V{g}VV \\
X @<{\pi}<< \mathrm{Bl}_Z X;
\end{CD}$$
where $f$ is a cover with branch divisor $B \subset X$, $g$ is a cover with branch divisor $B' \subset \mathrm{Bl}_Z X$, and $\pi$ is a blow-up with center $Z$. For simplicity, let $f,g$ both be finite of the same degree.
Is there a relationship between $Y$ and $\widetilde{\mathrm{Bl}_Z X}$? Is $\widetilde{\mathrm{Bl}_Z X}$ something like the blow-up of $Y$ with center $=$ double cover of $Z$, branched in $B \cap Z$? In other words, do we have $\widetilde{\mathrm{Bl}_Z X} \cong \mathrm{Bl}_{B \cap f^*(Z)} Y$?

Is $f$ flat? If so, the base change is the blowup you’re looking for.

Ah, thanks very much!
